# Auto trigger mouse click event on graph drawn from starting to ending of the graph?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, chap-links-library

```
    graph1 = new links.Graph(document.getElementById('adasLineChart1'));
    graph1.draw(data1, options1);


    links.events.addListener(graph1, "selectItem", function(event) {

    });
```

I am looking something like auto trigger of the graph mouse click event programmatic from starting to ending of the graph without manual mouse click, sample:

```
function counter(){

//trigger graph event similar to mouse on click event.
}
```